# PHP Copy command failing when spaces?

Tags: php, copy

I am executing the following commands:

```
<?php
copy ("http://localhost/.../DSCF8253.JPG" , "sites/default/files/DSCF8253.JPG"); // Success!
copy ("http://localhost/.../DSCF8260.JPG" , "sites/default/files/DSCF8260.JPG"); // Success!
copy ("http://localhost/.../HERMAN 085.jpg" , "sites/default/files/HERMAN 085.jpg" ); // Fail!
?>
```

The first two copy fine, but not the last one. Why?

It must have something to do with the filenames (the last one has a SPACE before the 085).

Any help would be  greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` say?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the space by replacing it with `%20` in the URL?

Comment: Are the source directories the same?

Comment: Also, you are aware that when on localhost, instead of using slow http transport, you could use a file path (that would probably work with the spaces as well)?

Comment: @Pekka: I am actually copying from one website to another. I wish I could use filepaths instead, but I can't for what I'm doing.

Comment: @Justin: I need a generic solution that will work for all weird scenarios. I.e. I need to pinpoint the real problem, and not just solve it for the one case.

Comment: Understood, what I was getting at was that if this was the underlying solution (which does not appear to be the case), you could identify it as such. From there, implementing a generic solution is a straightforward task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
http://localhost/.../HERMAN 085.jpg
```

Should be

```
http://localhost/.../HERMAN%20085.jpg
```

Copy & the http wrappers are less forgiving then browsers / user-agents when it comes to invalid urls. A space in an url is invalid, so it should be [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/urlencode)'d.

Comment: Still doesn't work, but ur definitely on the right path. I used urlencode with no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'd check the webserver's access logs to check whether the request is OK & returns data. If that still fails, I'd look into packages like `cURL` & `httprequest` to see if they can manage.

Comment: CURL ended up being the best solution.

Comment: Sort of.  If you fully urlencode the whole URL, it will fail as well.  As far as I can tell from testing, the space is one of the few characters that it will not interpret properly.  Ghetto, but I'd suggest doing a str_replace to change spaces to %20.

Comment: Check out `rawurlencode` it solved my problem in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 3):

```
//i used this code once i tried to copy images to a wordpress site and set post featured image
//i only mentioned the part you want and did not mention other parts
$image_url = 'http://example.com/images/my image with spaces.jpg';
try {
    //throw exception if can't move the file

    if (!copy(str_replace(" ","%20",$image_url),$file)) {
        $errors = error_get_last();
        throw new Exception('Could not copy file');
    }   

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
 //using urlencode will corrupt the url if used with the full url
 //it will generate something like http%dsf%swdfablablabla
 //if you need to encode you will encode anything after http://yoursite.com/{encode only works here}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strangest thing: the %20 way doesn't seem to do the trick, but after some trying
in vain (first with %20, then quoting the filename, then double-quoting, then
protecting spaces, tell me if I missed something), now the original version works flawlessly.  This is Windows 10, PHP 5.5.12 and we are in year 2016.
Good luck with all these deterministic, finite-state systems :)

**A possible solution** btw, is to use exec() and do a copy on the operating
system level.  Then again, it's OS specific.