# Placing an instructional message inside an email via link

Tags: php, email

Ok, this might sound like a really stupid question and I'm really not sure if it's possible but I thought I'd just throw it out there.

Is there any way to place a message inside an email that is linked from your website - I.E. if someone clicks on an "E-Mail Me" link so that their email editor opens up, is there any way of displaying an instructional message inside the email that they are about to send?

Comment: yes, if you are talking about <a href="mailto:youemail@email.com">

Comment: Checkout this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto