# get author email for single post

Tags: wordpress, post, mailto, author

Hello All I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have multiple users for my blog and they are allowed to create posts. I would like to create a mailto: link on the single.php post for that specific post type. I would like the mailto: email to be the author's email of that specific posts so that a viewer could email the author of the post.

I am aware that wordpress has the function:

```
<?php $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_email'); ?>
```

this function stores the data, i would really appreciate it if someone could help me display a mailto: link with this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `echo` the value where you need it. For example:

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo get_the_author_meta('user_email'); ?>">Click here to email author</a>
```

Or, more readable:

```
<?php 
    $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_email'); 
    echo '<a href="mailto:' . $user_email . '">Click here to email author</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response Mevius. i was wondering if i could store that data in a variable then execute it without displaying the actual email maybe something like "click here to email author"

Comment: `<?php 
    $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_email'); 
    echo '<a href="mailto:' . $user_email . '"> click here to email author</a>';
?>` THANK you very much mevius

Comment: is there a way to get the title of the post as the subject of the email.? or any metakey for example i have a metakey "name" could this potentially be used as a subject for teh email?

Comment: Definitely! See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto) for more info. You can `echo` the post title with `<?php the_title(); ?>`.

Comment: `<?php 
    $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_email');
    $subject_title= get_the_title(); 
    echo '<a href="mailto:' . $user_email . '?subject= $subject_title "> click here to email agency</a>';
?>
` i tried something like this but it isnt working any thoughts?

Comment: always confused with the ' thank you so very much again.

Comment: The single quotes `'` end a string. The dots `.` "concatenate" a variable to the string. Another dot `.` after the variable and another single quote `'` starts the string up again. In other words, the strings are surrounded in single quotes and variables are attached to them with the dots.