# Open Outlook and preset email, subject and body using HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new in Javascript and I would like to make a small offline tool that opens up Outlook, and presets the email in the "To" section, presets the default Subject, and presets the body of the email with text from a textarea.

I would need the text area so that I can modify the email content whenever I want.

For now, I have the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:yourname@yoursite.com" enctype="text/plain">
   <input type=text name=your_content>
   <input type=submit value="Submit Your Content">
</form>
```

However, when I submit, Outlook opens, and the name attributes' values appear before my text.

Is there a way to avoid adding the name's value in my email, replace input with textarea and add the above mentioned things?

Thanks!

Comment: this is not what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the method to `GET` so it behaves more like an anchor tag and puts your values into url parameters instead of a post body. You will have to set the input names to valid `mailto:` values like body & subject

```
<form method="GET" action="mailto:yourname@yoursite.com" enctype="text/plain">
   <input type=text name="body">
   <input type=submit value="Submit Your Comments">
</form>
```

note that there is a max url size of ~2k characters

Comment: Thank you! It works, however, is there any chance that I might be able to replace the input (body) with a textarea?

Comment: Try it out! `<textarea name="body"></textarea>`

Comment: It seems that the form code above does not work for me, since I noticed it adds plus sign between the words I have there. The form practically acts as I build a link, and adds plus signs instead of white space. Is there another way I can get this done? Thanks!