# how to open ms office outlook in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, outlook

I use Html, jQuery for web designing. In my page, I have an *email id* as hyperlink on click of which, Microsoft office outlook should get opened with the *email id* in **To:** field and a static text as subject line. Can any one please tell me how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I set subject/content of email with using mailto:?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
<a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>
```

Some examples are available [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/learn-mailto-syntax/6748/)