# The command line argument is not valid verify the switch you are using

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, mailto

I am trying to open a Outlook when user clicks on submit button of form by using javascript mailto:

When I submit the form from chrome or firefox then it is able to open but in IE I am getting the following error:

**The command line argument is not valid verify the switch you are using**

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: mailto: links will use the default mail client set by the browser's settings.  It really has nothing to do with code.

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft Knowledge Base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312346) was helpful, but it was only a workaround:

- i.e. if I change my default program to "Mail Express" (Windows 10), clicking mailto in IE does **not** cause issue; the email opens in "Mail Express" and can be sent immediately
- However, if I change default program back to "Outlook 2016" (Windows 10), clicking mailto in IE **does cause** the issue: "The command line argument is not valid verify the switch you are using"

**Problem:**

My mailto value comes from Angular, and my mailto has special characters. I can only recreate this issue using [Angular's `ng-href` (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/theredpea/r80vpjhw/2/) I cannot recreate the issue with [plain HTML (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/4tz8tsg2/4/)).

**Solution:**

[Solution JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r80vpjhw/5/); again my problem is specific to Angular/`ng-href`, so my solution uses Angular/`ng-href`.

In my case my mailto href attribute value included double-quotes (i.e. `'"'`). The double quotes were **escaped** (with a backslash), but they **weren't encoded** I needed to URLEncode my mailto value. This is intuitive because `href` attribute usually points at a URL, and [URLs require percent-encoding.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

```
<a href="mailto:person@place.com?subject=Subject includes \"double-quotes\"">Mail link</a>
```

When I `encodeURIComponent` only the **`subject`** value: `encodeURIComponent("Subject includes \"double-quotes\"")` and update that part. The result is here; notice %20 and %22 in the new subject:

```
<a href="mailto:person@place.com?subject=Subject%20includes%20%22double-quotes%22">Mail link</a>
```

**Note**:

I had double-quotes (i.e. `'"'`, or %22), but a **different** character **may** cause the issue: I suspect [other URL-unsafe characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) may cause this issue.

Looks like the space (i.e. `' '` , or %20), was not causing a problem, even *before* encoding. *After* I started using `encodeURIComponent`, I probably fixed **any/all other** fancy characters that may have caused the issue, i.e. `'&'` or others...)

I'm not sure if the [parameters have different requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782084/1175496); i.e. is `subject` parameter treated differently than the `body` parameter, or the implied `to` parameter. So I used `encodeURIComponent` for both `subject` and `body`.

Be careful *not* to over-encode. Only encode the separate `subject` and `body` parameters:

- Do **not** encode the  colon (i.e. `:` which follows `mailto`); browsers may fail to recognize this is a mailto link (see solution)
- Do **not** encode the question marks (i.e. `?`) or the equals signs (i.e. `=`); browsers/Outlook may fail to parse the parameters (see solution)

So when I encode:

```
encodeURIComponent("mailto:person@place.com?subject=Subject includes \"double-quotes\"")
```

Notice the results; wrongly encoded the colon (i.e. %3A) and the equals sign (%3D)

```
 "mailto%3Aperson%40place.com%3Fsubject%3DSubject%20includes%20%22double-quotes%22"
```

Be careful not to *double-encode*, i.e. encode a string which is already encoded!

I will remove the Java tag from the question; I agree with comments [I don't think Java is relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981202/the-command-line-argument-is-not-valid-verify-the-switch-you-are-using/48119246#comment49992950_30981202)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure you did research much, but the first result in google when you look up for the error leads to a Microsoft board where it seems to be solved:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312346

As far as I've seen, your problem is related with a file association to the URI Schema "mailto". I'd recommend following the steps you can find in the link and searching exhaustively next time.

Comment: The link is dead, which is why its usually not recommended to just put a link without quoting the steps in the link