# Email button: subject and body text for mailto link

Tags: email, button, mailto, subject

I have a button to send an e-mail message. This opens a new e-mail but the problem is that the subject and the body text are not added to the e-mail message. This is what I have so far that is not working:

```
<input style="background: #4a5e70; color: #ffffff;" type="button" value="REQUEST INVITE" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:me@any.com’;” subject=“Request%20invite;body=Hallo%20you;”/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost every language (PowerShell is one exception), text strings are delimited by typewriter quotes (`'` and `"`) not typographic quotes (`‘`, `’`, `“` or `”`). You should replace your quotes like so:

```
onclick="window.location.href='mailto:me@any.com?subject=Request%20invite&body=Hallo%20you'"
```

The `onclick` attribute is written as a single string (delimited by double quotes) whose `href` whose value is a single string (delimited by single quotes) expressed as a URL-encoded query string.

Note also that you can’t rely on *mailto* links working unless users have configured a local email client correctly.

See the [Mailto Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) and this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto) for more information.