# How to send an email by javascript

Tags: javascript, email

I am making a simple website where we save something by email; i found out how to open the email, but i cant get it to email a specific thing.

this is my code:

```
     var a = function(){
 b = document.getElementById("email").value;
 m = document.getElementById("Text").value;
window.open("mailto:"+b);
};
```

I'm trying to make it so it emails m as the body.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links

Answer (score 1):

You can add `body` parameter like this:

```
window.open("mailto:"+b+"?body="+m);
```

`subject` parameter will be useful too

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782084/819764) will be helpful.