# Adding subject to a HTML email template

Tags: html, email, templates

Is it possible to add a subject with a html code inside the email template. 
I have googled it and have only found the possibility for link to do that.

```
<A HREF="mailto:test@example.com?subject=testing out mailto">First Example</A>
```

When clicking this it will automatically fill it.
But is there a possibility to define it inside the email template ?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "HTML code inside the email template", can you clarify? What/where is the template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set subject/content of email with using mailto:?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto)