# Using mailto with auto populated subject

Tags: html, mailto

Is it possible to have a mailto link in the body of an email that populates the subject of the email to be sent using the original email subject?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort

Comment: do you need to use inside another email. Question is not clear. You can set subject even content for the email