# Passing variable to mailto subject

Tags: mailto

so I'm trying to pass the value of "x" here which will generate the random value.

```
<script>

  var result = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,5);
  window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById("x").innerHTML=result;
  } 

</script>
```

I want to pass the value to my html code, in the mailto subject. so when people click the link, it will automatically open the default mail and send the email to info@legianbeachbali.com with the subject "Special Promotion + (random code)"

```
<p style="color: #5b5b5b; text-align: left; id: x;">
<a title="Book Now" href="mailto:info@legianbeachbali.com?subject=Special%20Promotion%20"+x>Book Directly with Us</a></p>
```

I tried to call the value on id and put "x" in the subject but as I expected, it doesn't work. could you guys please help me? I need to know how to show the value in the subject email.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove + x from your HTML i.e, **href** attribute of your **a** tag.
Then add **id** to you **a** tag **mailTo** in this case (as shown below).

```js
$(function() {
 
 var result = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,5);
 var href =  $("#mailTo").attr('href')  
 var  newHref = href + result
 $("#mailTo").attr("href", newHref)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="Book Now" id='mailTo' href="mailto:info@legianbeachbali.com?subject=Special%20Promotion%20">Book Directly with Us</a></p>
```

Comment: nah, it still not working. i just saw your code and it is not generates a random code, it is more like you put the code manually. so the code is always the same everytime i click the link

Comment: @AnindyaSantikaDevi Random code I took it from your question you can modify it as you want

Comment: i put the javascript above the a tag, but it still not working