# How do I validate form and send input values with ::mailto with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, onclick, onsubmit

I have a form in which I want to:

- Validate with JavaScript
- When the validation is done, I want to "sort" of make a callback function much like `sendMail();` function (See code example below).

To make my question more clear, what I want is to "mix" the `onclick` and `onsubmit` functions so that the `Validation()` function calls. And when it validates the page, then I want to call the `sendMail()` function.

Any ideas?
Thank you beforehand!

#### Code:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erikos93/6qnuou24/)

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" name="vForm">

            <div>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="username" class="textInput" placeholder="Username">
                <div id="name_error" class="val_error"></div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="register" value="Register">
            </div>

        </form>
```

**JS:**

```
    var username = document.forms["vForm"]["username"];

         function Validate(){
            // VALIDATE USERNAME
            if(username.value == ""){
                name_error.textContent = "Username is required";
                username.style.border = "1px solid red";
                username.focus();
                return false;
            }

// ADD EVENT LISTENERS
    function nameVerify(){
        if (username.value != "") {
            name_error.innerHTML = "";
            username.style.border = "1px solid #110E0F";
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**HTML - sendMail(); :**

```
<textarea id="myText">
    Text that will be sent to body of email.
</textarea>

<button onclick="sendMail(); return false">Send</button>
```

**JS - sendMail(); :**

```
function sendMail() {
        var link = "mailto:example@mail.com"
                 + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
                 + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
                 + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value)
        ;
    
        window.location.href = link;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto

Answer (score 0):

suggest use the jquery plugin

[Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

and the callback function you can use the submitHandler.