# Send message in HTML form

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv5CU.jpg)I was currently working on my professional site that I purchased it template, there is a contact me form. I have tried different varies of editors and videos and some forums. I need some assistance. I Listed the code below. when I click the Send message button it opened the users email client, but the information in the form like name, email, subject, and message do not carry over. I have tried different things nothing works please help.

```
<i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>

<div class="col l7 m7 s12">
   <form class="contact-form center-align" action="#">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Subject">
      <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <a href="mailto:email@domain.com?Name?Email?Subject?Message" class="custom-btn waves-effect waves-light">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          send message
      </a>
   </form>
</div>here
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set subject/content of email with using mailto:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto)

Comment: Added a photo of the contact form on my site, which goes with the form code i provided in the post

Answer (score 0):

the pattern should be: mailto:email followed by a question mark and then an ampersand list of parameter names and values.

E.G.

```
"mailto:mark.mather82@outlook.com?body=your email text&subject=your email subject"
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the message and name parameters but these are invalid anyway so i have omitted them.

Comment: like i said before in my initial post it was a template i purchased and the code was already, all i had to do was program the send message button but nothing was working right. i researched videos and read other forums wasnt getting the answer i need.

Answer (score 0):

You seems not to know what is the mailto link type, or at least how to use it.

The **mailto** link accept the following parameters :

- *mailto*: the email recipiant address
- *cc*: the carbon copy email address
- *bcc*: the blind carbon copy email address
- *subject*: the subject of your email
- *body*: the content of your email

Your `Name`, `Email` and `Message` parameters are not valid parameters in HTML.

Also, about delimiters :

- *?* is the first parameter delimiter
- *&* is the other parameters delimiter

Knowing all that, you can now pretty easily create your link :

```
<a href="mailto:mark.mather82@outlook.com?subject=Your%20Subject&body=The%20body%20of%20the%20email">
```

*N.B:* In order to have spaces in your *Subject* and *Body*, you must replace every spaces with `%20`

[Here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.htm) is a pretty clear and precise article about **mailto** links that I really recommend you to read, from which I get almost all the informations about **mailto** links.