# how to bind tabular formate data in outlook in asp.net after uploading to server

Tags: jquery, outlook

we need to open Outlook with and auto fill data in table format in asp.net.

can someone please give me a solution?

Comment: Not possible because that would allow access to a users file system which is a huge security risk.  Use a form + file upload instead.

Comment: can we use active x controls to solve my coding problem?

Comment: No, browser hosted ActiveX is not supported/available any more.

Comment: what else can we use instead of activex controls?

Comment: Without installing custom software on every users machine, what you want is not possible.

Comment: You mean to say we can not pass command from browsers to OS without installing custom software?

Comment: mailto: is the only way to do that & it just allows address, subject & text content https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto

Comment: Thanks Alex..but I think we can't pass HTML table through mailto...let me know if I am  wrong.

Comment: You cannot use HTML.