# Email Button Link to not display security warning

Tags: php

I have a php landing page with a simple button in a form area on the page for a user to contact

I'm using this:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:info@<?php echo preg_replace('/^www./','',$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]); ?>?subject=Landing contact&body=Hi, I found your website and would like some more information, please." >
```

but I find that it shows an (security warning) unsecure message if clicked on..evem though a cert is in place and active

so I tried this:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:info@<?php echo "{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}";  ?>?subject=Landing contact&body=Hi, I found your website and would like some more information, please." >
```

Is threre a way to do this using the https protocol and not get that error message?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: My first guess is it doesn't like un-encoded strings in the subject and body. I'd check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto.

Comment: What does the security exception say exactly?

Comment: What is the `security warning`'s content?

Comment: All I was getting was the standard Google security warning - I gave up on it and just used a href email link instead... oh well...