# Can you pre-fill parts of an email using mailto?

Tags: html, html-email, mailto

I know you can use `mailto:` to add a subject line or CC/BCC other people, but is there a way you can add some body text, or a signature line to an email?

For example: if you wanted to have a line at the end of the email that said:

> "Mailed from yoursite.com"

Just so you could know that they used a link from your site. Is this possible without using a form or a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **How do you add a signature to a mailto without PHP (or equivalent)?**

While your answer was sort of vague, you could try something like this, where you write something at the top and have a few carriage returns (`%0D`) followed by the signature `Mailed from yoursite.com`. `%20` can be used to ensure that the browser displays spaces correctly.

`<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Hello%20there&body=Body%20stuff%20goes%20here.%0D%0DMailed%20from%20yoursite.com">Send Mail</a>`

You can take a look at [this w3 schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto) or [this discussion (as mentioned by Obsidian Age)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto).

Comment: Works exactly the way I wanted it to. Thanks.