# How do I add HTML form data to a mailto link

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to create a form that allows the user to type their first and last name, then submit it. I want to take the first and last name they entered and put that data in a mailto link. The code below is what I have. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="form">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
        <button type="submit" class="submit" onclick="submitForm()"><i class="material-icons md-24">play_circle_filled</i></button>
    </form>
    <script>
    function submitForm{
        var fname = get.getElementsByName("firstname").value;
        var lname = get.getElementsByName("lastname").value;
        window.open("mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Test%20Email&body=First%20Name:%20"+fname+"%20Last%20Name:"+lname"");
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75755452/14344959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function submitForm(form) {
  window.open("mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Test%20Email&body=First%20Name:%20" + form.firstname.value + "%20Last%20Name:" + form.lastname.value);
  return false; /* cancel submit or else page reloads */
}

<form onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" />
  <button type="submit" class="submit"><i class="material-icons md-24">play_circle_filled</i></button>
</form>
```

BTW, below are mistakes in your code.

```
:"+lname""); /*unwanted "" at the end*/
```

Here, you have multiple corrections:

```
get.getElementsByName("firstname").value
```

It is not `get.` instead it is `document.`, also `getElementsByName()` will return you `NodeList` instead of just one HTML Element, so likewise you will need to use index, so you end up with `document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value`

Answer (score 2):

First, you forgot the parenthesis after the functions name (like Erl V stated).
Funktions always have these parentheses. You can use them, to give the functions parameters. Read more about functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

Second, you forgot a plus sign in the concatenated string of the window.open parameter.
I removed the last part, cause it was unnecessary.

Third, you was using `get.getElementsByName("firstname").value` instead of `document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value`.

This is tested and should work:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
    <button type="submit" class="submit" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function submitForm(){
    var fname = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
    var lname = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value;
    window.open("mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Test%20Email&body=First%20Name:%20"+fname+"%20Last%20Name:"+lname);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**: Cleaned your javascript

```
function submitForm(){
    var fname = document.getElementsByName("firstname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementsByName("lastname").value;
    window.open("mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Test%20Email&body=First%20Name:%20"+fname+"%20Last%20Name:"+lname);
}
```

Comment: That did not fix it.

Comment: @KevinLong also remove the last double qoute in your script.

Comment: @KevinLong, I edited my answer. Found a lot of syntax errors in your script