# Add subject line in HTML

Tags: html, html-email, mailto

I'm trying to add a hyperlink using HTML. When a sender clicks a link, I would like the browser to create a new email with a filled out To field and subject line.

## Code

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you.<br>
    <a href="mailto:aaa@company.com">test</a> 
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set subject/content of email using mailto:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
<a href="mailto:aaa@company.com?subject=Testing out mailto!">test</a>
```

If you would like to add a BCC and CC, you can add the following:

```
<a href="mailto:aaa@company.com?subject=Testing email&bcc=bcc_email@gmail.com&cc=cc_email@gmail.com">test</a>
```

See more details on this method [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000056.htm).