# Is there a way to put "subject" into the function:mailto in a Datacolumn in yii2?

Tags: yii2

The problem is the following: I have an `Html::mailto()` in my `Datacolumn` where I wanna give the value of the subject with it. 
I can't use swiftmailer or some other extensions because I don't want to generate an email, instead, I want to open outlook, by clicking the hyperlink, and have the subject pre-written there.

This is the function:

```
public static function mailto($text, $email = null, $options = [])
```

This is my code:

```
 [   
   'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
   'attribute' => 'email',
   'label' => 'E-Mail',
   'format' => 'raw', 
   'value' => function($model){ 
        $email =  SucheBiete::find()    
            ->select(['email'])
            ->join('INNER JOIN', 'user', 'user.user_id = suche_biete.user_user_id')
            ->scalar();

             return Html::mailto('Kontaktaufnahme mit: ' . $email,$email, ['subject' => 'Hi There']);
    }
]
```

It works but without getting the subject:

[image]

is the `$option` parameter the right one to give a `subject`,`textbody` or `cc`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set subject/content of email using mailto:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto)

Comment: I saw a lof of code about mailto in my research, but still didnt know how to implement it in this specific situation. I tried a lot of things and was tired of it. So for me personally it is no duplicate :) Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to attach the subject to the second parameter:

```
return Html::mailto('...: ' . $email,"$email?subject=HiThere" );
```

Maybe you need to [encode()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#encode()-detail) the subject for preserving spaces.

Comment: it would work without the encoding just concatenate the string as you have done already.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much!