# Compose email on button click?

Tags: html, css

Trying to do this with HTML/CSS and hopefully not JS unless it’s necessary. Currently trying.

```
<a class=“button” href=“mailto:blah@blah.com”>blah</a>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, what exactly you want to achieve, please tell briefly! 
You want to send an email? or on what you are stuck you should've shared that as well

Comment: You definitely can't do that with just CSS ...

Comment: @user46812 this looks like it is already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto

Comment: @StuartDines doesn’t specify using a button so I’m not sure how this answers my question.

Comment: @Gosi so I need JS like now huh?

Comment: @nazifarashid im trying to make a button that will open your email client and compose a new email to my address

Comment: @StuartDines referenced a link containing the correct solution. You need an anchor tag; not a button, to accomplish this. How you style it is entirely up to you but anchor is the correct element.

Comment: You can't use javascript to send email, you need a server side language like PHP. There, you can set your reply to address.

Comment: @user46812 https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/
Check if this link helps you.

Comment: Currently I get an unsupported url message, which could be coming from the text editor I’m using to deploy the site.

Comment: Your code specifies an `a` tag. What, precisely is the problem and why is it not a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto ?

Comment: Also watch out for "curly quotes" .... e.g. : “ & ” , which you have in your code, you want regular quotes e.g. :`<a class="button" href="mailto:blah@blah.com">blah</a>` , with that typo fixed, your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @JonP you should post that as an answer. It is correct and works.

Comment: @Gosi , it's also just a typographical error, which is actually off topic.