# Can I create a link in an email to automatically send an email populated with specific information from the original email?

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, mailto, auto-populate

I would like to create a link inside a "noreply@...com" email sent to a client with specific information, for the client to be able to click and automatically generate an email (mailto) using the information from the original noreply email.

### Example:

From: noreply@example.com
to: client1@gmail.com

Subject: Thank you for participating in yesterdays event!

Body: Thank you CLIENTNAME for participating in yesterdays EVENTNAME event! If you would like to confirm you attended click HERE.

---

I would to add a link in the HERE word to generate an autopopulated email that says: "Hi my name is CLIENTNAME, and i attended your EVENTNAME event"

**This is an example and I know it does nothing productive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set subject/content of email using mailto:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create your link with a `subject` and `body` parameter.

```html
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?subject=Hello&body=This is my message">Email Us!</a>
```

You will need to escape any characters that might break the link... e.g. double quotes `"`

Answer (score 0):

The [mailto protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v%3Dvs.85)) is described in depth on MSDN pages. You can create a link in the email which can open a client's e-mail system and begins a new email message with a prepopulated fields.

### sAddress

One or more valid e-mail addresses separated by a semicolon. You must use Internet-safe characters, such as %20 for the space character.

### sHeaders

Optional. One or more name-value pairs. The first pair should be prefixed by a "?" and any additional pairs should be prefixed by a "&". The name can be one of the following strings.

- subject

  Text to appear in the subject line of the message.
- body

  Text to appear in the body of the message.
- CC

  Addresses to be included in the "cc" (carbon copy) section of the message.
- BCC

  Addresses to be included in the "bcc" (blind carbon copy) section of the message.

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?
    subject=MessageTitle&amp;
    body=Message Content">
    Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. My question is for it to be used in mass mail campaign, and the mailto link be mass tailored populated with information included in the originally sent mail. Example. It would pull specific words from the body of the original message.

Comment: Unfortunately, most email clients applications support any script execution in the message bodies. For example, for security purposes Microsoft Office Outlook blocks scripts in message bodies.