# open outlook new email with content in client machine using asp.net core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, outlook, html-email, office-interop

After lot of analysis I created an sample application with MVC Core where I used HTML email template (with some styles n layout) to open outlook message which populated the template with styles and pre configured data. I was able to add my custom data from the View/Controller to the template. everything is good. but when it comes to opening outlook I used the Microsoft.Interop to work with outlook.
It was working fine in my local IIS express as it opens up the draft message.

but It goes to IIS server troubles started.
what I had ignored was - the requirement was to open the outlook message on client machine but with above design it would open up in the server rather than client (who browses the web app).
on top of that I hit another road block - Interop failed to initialize as it needs 32BIT mode to be enabled for initialization, if I turn on 32bit app true at pool level then entire MVC core modules started failing as its not win32.
So, finally the design isnt apt as I should agree.
with this requirement - what is the best way to achieve this?

Should I give up saying - with Web you would never able to open outlook message with styles/colors in the message? rather I should give another form to the user to open web form with details for correction and then they can send using app itself? instead of outlook?

I was able to open JavaScript to open the outlook message at client side but HTML formats arnt coming out as we know that styles wont render.

any better solutions? which I am missing?

I am using asp.net core 2.2 version btw.

Comment: if you have a heavily styled form, better to provide a web interface, otherwise you can [set subject and body contents of the email using `emailto:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782084/5519026) property.

Comment: Thanks for your response Laz Ziya; however, mailto is only plain text it doesnt render html tags on the outlook body. Tried this option and it doest help in my case.