# Mailto link that adds current domain name to subject line

Tags: javascript, email, mailto

I'm trying to create a mailto link that programmatically includes the current domain in the mail subject when clicked.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="cta">
Make an enquiry at <a href="javascript:'mailto:sales@hashimaziz.com?subject=Sales%20Inquiry%20RE:%20' + window.location.hostname;">sales@hashimaziz.com</a>
</div>
```

The JavaScript itself seems to work, but when the mailto link is clicked, it goes to a white page that prints the text of the `mailto` command itself. This can be tested on the website itself [here](https://latestfooty.co.uk).

What's wrong with the `mailto` link that's preventing it from behaving as it should?

Comment: Why do you have both `javascript:` and `mailto:`?

Comment: @Pointy To add the domain name to the subject line.

Comment: Well ultimately you can't 100% rely on mail user agents paying any attention to the subject parameter.

Comment: @Pointy The mailto `subject` and `body` syntax are a [part of the RFC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41365892/1191147), I can't see any modern mail client not supporting them.

Comment: Not everybody is using a "modern mail client", and web mail clients won't pay attention to the `mailto:` links at all (at least mine, GMail, doesn't)

Comment: @Pointy Neither does Outlook.com. Unfortunately `mailto` links were never really designed for web mail clients, I'm mainly using it to cover the standalone mail clients while ensuring the address itself is visible to copy for web mail clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript URLs, when navigated to, evaluate an expression and print it.

You can use:

```html
<div class="cta">
Make an enquiry at <a href="javascript:void(window.location.href%3D'mailto%3Asales%40hashimaziz.com%3Fsubject%3DSales%2520Inquiry%2520RE%3A%2520'%2Bwindow.location.hostname)">sales@hashimaziz.com</a>
</div>
```

Or, possibly better:

```html
<div class="cta">
    Make an enquiry at <a id="contact-link">sales@hashimaziz.com</a>
</div>

<!-- New script tag not necessary. -->
<script>
    document.getElementById("contact-link").href = 'mailto:sales@hashimaziz.com?subject=Sales%20Inquiry%20RE:%20' + window.location.hostname;
</script>
```

Comment: Scratch that, it doesn't seem to actually add the current domain at the end, so the only thing in the subject line is `Sales Inquiry RE:`.

Comment: Did you use the first solution or the second one?

Comment: The inline one, purely because I wanted to avoid externalising the code anywhere else for such a small piece of JS.

Comment: It seems to work in Firefox (not when I type it in the address bar, though).

Comment: Also using Firefox, but when clicking the `mailto` link, no subject is shown, at least on Windows 10's Mail app. I'll try the other method to see if the inline solution is the problem.

Comment: I updated the inline solution with a properly encoded URI, but that may not be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, can confirm the inline solution behaves the same. Testing the second solution now.

Comment: The script solution behaves in the same way, tested on both Windows 10's native Mail client and Mozilla Thunderbird.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. I have tested in Firefox an Chrome (both with the Windows 10 Mail app) and it works just fine.

Comment: My bad, turns out the issue was that I was testing it locally, which it doesn't see as having a domain. I tested the inline version on the live site and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help with this.