# Angular 10: How to add query parameters to the link

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a link like

```html
<a class="contact-email" href="mailto:cybertruck@wrapmate.com">cybertruck@wrapmate.com</a>
```

I need to change `href` so that something like this comes out.

```html
mailto:cybertruck@wrapmate.com?subject=Cybertruck%20Request&body=%matte%+%color%
```

How to add query parameters to such a link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set subject/content of email using mailto:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto)

Comment: partially, but can I put the selected color parameters into the body?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic example to do this is append the `selectedValue` from the dropdown at the end of the `href`.

```html
<p>
  <a [href]="'mailto:cybertruck@wrapmate.com?subject=Cybertruck%20Request&body=' + selectedValue">Send an email</a>
</p>
```

Here's the full HTML of the page with some dummy data coming from the component. The value gets updated in the `ngModel`, so it's usable everywhere on the page.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item.name">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>

<p>You selected: {{ selectedValue }}</p>

<p *ngIf="selectedValue">
  <a [href]="'mailto:cybertruck@wrapmate.com?subject=Cybertruck%20Request&body=' + selectedValue">Send an email</a>
</p>
```

To see this in action, follow [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-afsmyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).