# Identify default email app of the user's device/system

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an email sending functionality that i am working on. The requirement is

**The user should be directed to the default mail app of their respective device**

Outlook uses mailto
Gmail uses https://mail.google.com/mail/
and so on.

Is there a way to identify the default email app of the user which can be system or mobile device?

Comment: I think the only way to invoke default mail application on client machine is using mailto: and it is already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto

Comment: I have verified this. It doesn't work if your system is configured to google chrome or some other browser as the default email app. In that case, mailto will redirect to the browser with a new tab open .For it to work, we need to configure the google share url https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&to=" + email_address.  So i end up configuring mailto &the gmail address which is what i want to elliminate.