# can I make an HTML button that automatically Inserts another HTML page to mailto:example@gmail.com

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gmail

as the gif shows, I want to use the inline HTML button to open the reply and create new HTML elements inside the reply message box is this possible?

[image]

Comment: So, you want someone to be able to reply to your email?

Comment: Yes with a script witch auto inserts a new HTML- into the reply.

Comment: And what's wrong with the normal reply mechanism?

Comment: nothing, I just want to automate it.

someone would not copy and paste HTML code inside the reply message box.

Comment: They don't need to - if they click the normal reply button it does the automation you're after. You don't need to put a button in the email.

Comment: You can inject a body into the `<a href="mailto:email@email.com">text</a>` tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto but it depends what email client the recipient is using as to whether it'll work or not.