# Share with email with HTML markdown from the front-end

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, email, html-email

Is there any way I can allow users to share the article with the HTML markdown within email?

I tried to create the link like shown below, but it just pastes the HTML code without formatting in the email client:

```html
      <a href={`mailto:email@example.com?subject='Hello from Abstract!'&body=<a href="https://google.com/">some link</a>`}>
        Click to Send an Email
      </a>
```

`next-share` library also does the same:

```js
    <EmailShareButton
        url={url}
        subject={title}
        body={'<a href="https://google.com/">some link</a>'}
      >
        Click to Send an Email
      </EmailShareButton>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set subject/content of email using mailto:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto)

Comment: No. What I want to achieve is to have email body formated (with bold text, images, text links, and so on)

Comment: The chosen answer has a comment which answers your question _That is entirely client specific. In the general case, no._