# How To Get Body Of Email To Autofill

Tags: html, html-email, autofill

I am VERY new to HTML, but I do have a basic thing working as a knowledgebase for my job.
I have managed to get it so that I can click on an email address to open Outlook and have the email address and subject fields already populated with the information needed. (That has been thanks to this site!)
Now, I would like to be able to expand on that and have the body of text in the email to autofill too (there are a lot of repeat / basic emails that we send).
Can any of you clever people out there explain how I do this, as if talking to a child (assume I know nothing, because that is basically where I am at hahaha).
Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.
**PLEASE NOTE - I am using Notepad++ to write this HTML code for the little basic site I am using - I do not have any other programmes to use to do this. That is how basic I am!
H

I don't know what to try - I have Googled and I have tried searching this site but, like Bono, I can't find what I am looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set subject/content of email using mailto:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-using-mailto)

Comment: Depending on your company's ESP you can use content objects which are snippets of reusable content with things like URLs, params, and other content pre-filled.

Comment: HI Richard, thanks for this. This might answer my question - I will get my husband to look it over when he is back from his work trip. Thanks for your help (I honestly don't understand any of this very much as using Notepad++ to try and write HTML will probably show hahaha)