# file_get_contents() with no response - php

Tags: php, web-services

I am trying to call a web service which basicaly looks like this:

```
http://10.10.10.10:8080/gw/someAction?amount=10&description='Some description'
```

So this is how i call this web service:

```
$endpoint = "http://10.10.10.10:8080/gw/someAction?amount=10&description='Some description'";

    $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/xml'
            )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create( $opts );

    $result = file_get_contents( $endpoint, false, $context );
    $xml_result = simplexml_load_string( $result );
    echo $xml_result->success;
```

So here, i got nothing, the xml_result is empty. And here is the interesting part - when i remove the blank space from the description:

```
 http://10.10.10.10:8080/gw/someAction?amount=10&description='Somedescription'
```

Everything is just fine, I got the answer from the web service. Also tried to call the web service with the chrome rest client WITH the blank space in the description and everything is OK, i have response. So this leads me to some kind of PHP problem here with the blank spaces in the web service. Please, help !

UPDATE:

```
print_r($result)
```

results in

```
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a valid URL, spaces must be escaped:

```
http://10.10.10.10:8080/gw/someAction?amount=10&description='Some%20description'
```

You might want to take a look at [How to properly URL encode a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php).

Comment: Didn`t work..alto tried urlencode() with no success.

Comment: rawurlencode() only for the description parameter did the job