# how do I get a number of all incidents that have happened in a month via jira api

Tags: php, api, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to create a page that will show me how many incidents have happened within a month via the Jira api, I'm not sure the best way to fo this as I have looked through the jira api docs but that is not described within.

Comment: I have an array being returned but I'm not sure how to only get this information ' `Array
(
    [expand] => schema,names
    [startAt] => 0
    [maxResults] => 5
    [total] => 840
    [issues] => Array
        (` I want to pull back the total amount of incidents.

Comment: The `total` (numeric) is how many "incidents" were found. The `startAt` and `maxResults` are for the paging. In your example, the answer is: 840.

Answer (score 0):

If by "how many incidents happened" you mean "how many issues were created" you can do a JQL search, which gives you a total count of issues within specified JQL query.

So to find issues created in February 2016 you should use the following JQL: `created >= 2016-02-01 AND created <= 2016-02-29`. The REST API endpoint that lets you perform a JQL search is [/api/2/search](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/search).

In our example (issues created in February) you need to send a GET request to:

`{YOUR_JIRA_BASE_URL}/rest/api/2/search?jql=created%20>=%202016-02-01%20AND%20created%20<=%202016-02-29`

(don't forget to [properly encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php) the query string)

To save bandwidth you can discard issues data and retrieve only the count by adding a `maxResults` parameter set to 0:

`{YOUR_JIRA_BASE_URL}/rest/api/2/search?maxResults=0&jql=created%20>=%202016-02-01%20AND%20created%20<=%202016-02-29`

Here's a concrete example using the Apache's JIRA: [Issues created in February](https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/search?maxResults=0&jql=created%20%3E=%202016-02-01%20AND%20created%20%3C=%202016-02-29)

### REFERENCE

JQL is quite powerful so you can narrow down your search even further (e.g. specify project to count the issues for). Read more about it [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues) and [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/blog/2015/06/search-jira-like-a-boss-with-jql)