# WordPress stop/remove http:// from prepending to esc_url

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a control/setting in my WordPress Customizer that takes an address input by the user and enters it into the url of a Google Map embeded on the page. I'm using esc_html to convert the address (Example: `123 Main Street`) into the proper format (Example: `123%20Main%20Street`) but it's also prepending `http://` before it, which I do not need in this case. How do I remove the `http://`?

This is the code I have in my template file:

```
<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'address' , __( '123 Main Street', 'myTheme' ) )); ?>
```

This is the code I have in my customizer.php:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'address', array(
    'default'           => __( '123 Main Street', 'myTheme' ), 
) );    
$wp_customize->add_control( 'address', array(
    'label'             => __( 'Address', 'myTheme' ),
    'type'              => 'text',
    'section'           => 'map'
) );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly URL encode a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php)

Comment: I don't have much experience with wordpress, but after reading the documentation, it looks like `esc_url` returns an escaped URL afterwards. If that's the case, are you able to just remove the `http://` from the URL? `substr("http://123%20Main%20Street", 7);`. You could also, if possible and fits your needs, encode the text to be used in a URL rather than using Wordpress's built in function: `rawurlencode("123 Main Street");`

Comment: @bugfroggy `rawurlencode` worked beautifully. If you want to put it in as an answer I'll gladly accept it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two options you could use here: `urlencode()` and `rawurlencode()`.

`urlencode()`:

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs.

`rawurlencode()`:

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_.~ have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits.

Therefore, `urlencode("123 Main Street")` will return `123+Main+Street` and `rawurlencode("123 Main Street")` will return `123%20Main%20Street`. Choose whichever is best for you.

If it is necessary to use `esc_url()` as provided from WordPress, you could also just remove the `http://` from the string using `substr("http://123%20Main%20Street", 7);`. In this case, it will return an identical string to `rawurlencode()`.

Comment: Very thorough @bugfroggy! `rawurlencode` was the best solution for me:  `<?php echo rawurlencode( get_theme_mod( 'address' , __( '123 Main Street', 'myTheme' ) )); ?>` Thanks!