# How to encode get parameter from html form?

Tags: php, html, forms, encode, urlencode

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/web/" method="get">
<input type="search" name="keyword_search_query">
<input type="submit" value="Search…">
</form>
```

This is a search form for my website.

What is the right/common way to encode these data into a search query to avoid unexpected behavior?

For instance, having an `&` in one of the inputs will cut the search query. How should I escape those characters?

P.S. How does Google do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly URL encode a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

User `encodeURI(data);` for encoding

Comment: And what user has disabled JavaScript?

Comment: You're using php, so use a php function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php.

Comment: @David You can for user to enable Javascript or you can validate in PHP.