# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed because of hypen on url

Tags: php, html

Hi Im having trouble getting the content of the file from a url.
Here is my code:

```html
$link = file_get_contents("https://website.com/s/File-Name-Ext.xls");
```

I know the hypens are the one causing the error but I dont know what value to replace on this. Any suggestion will be a big help. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly URL encode a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Hi, this doesn't answer my question. What I did is replace hyphens to "%2D" on the link. When I type the link on the browser it is working but when I used it on my codes it's not.