# problem with sending notification from laravel controller to Telegram Channel

Tags: laravel, telegram

I want to send a notification after firing an event in my website such as adding a post , adding a news or etc ...

I have done the requirements ,making a channel , adding a bot into it with administrtor role to send notification , get token , chat_id , finally I have made the link if I paste it in my browser's addressbar and press enter , that message will be send , but the problem is I can't run it automatically

here is my created Link :
[https://api.telegram.org/bot[MY_Token]/sendMessage?chat_id=[MyChatId]&text=[My_TEXT]](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BMY_Token%5D/sendMessage?chat_id=%5BMyChatId%5D&text=%5BMy_TEXT%5D)
please help me ..

```
private function sendTelegram($token,$chat_id,$text){
```

$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$text."";
file_get_contents($url);
}

here is my error :
failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Please add some code samples of what exactly you have tried so far, and any errors you have ancountered

Comment: Did you encoded the url? If the 'text' contains spaces, the request will never reach the server if the url isn't escaped: [How to properly URL encode a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Why it works when I paste generated link in my browser ?  I use just a simple word to send but I have error , I couldn't find any solution for my problem, I am confused , how no one haven't used this method for awaring their website users , that the website has broadcast new post or anything else ...

Comment: I Solved it by myself !