# Get data passed as queryparams from Angular in Php?

Tags: php, angular

If i am sending data in query params from angular application i need to get those data in php from url. I am not familiar to php. Can anyone help me out yr?

Comment: Have you tried googling it? You look like you know what you want to do, we are here to help if you get stuck, come back and edit your question once you have tried something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a link in url for testing let say localhost/test/test.php?link=www.google.com

```
<?php
echo $_Get['link'];
```

Comment: This would produce: Undefined variable: _Get . You should use `$_GET`

Comment: @sukalogika i am using $_Get it is giving me correct result. But if the url contains "&" then the result comes what ever data is there before &. Is it any way to fetch data with &.

Comment: You should use encode that string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1):

In your php file,
check to see that you got the needed parameter.
If so, handle the call as you wish. Otherwise, you can send back an error.
An example:
If your query param is called "someParameter", then

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['someParameter'])) {
    $someParameter = $_GET['someParameter'];
    // Do something with it
}
else {
    $httpStatusCode = 400;
    $httpStatusMessage  = 'someParameter is missing';
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0';
    header($protocol.' '.$httpStatusCode.' '.$httpStatusMessage);
}
?>
```