# When I send mail using swiftmailer. Using files from other cloud services as attachments, as long as there are special characters

Tags: php, swiftmailer

When I send mail using swiftmailer, using files from other cloud services as attachments, as long as there are special characters, it will report this error：

> Unable to open path "https://xxxxxx/1664960211LNW1344-88%%%
> ￥￥￥nylon12Elastane.pdf".

```
$email = (new Email())
    ->from(new Address($smtpUser,$res['nickName']))
    ->to(...$res['sMailRecipient'])
    ->subject($res['sMailTitle'])
    ->html($res['sContent']);
    //CC
    if(!empty($res['sMailCc'])) $email->cc(...$res['sMailCc']);
    //BCC
    if(!empty($res['mailBcc'])) $email->bcc(...$res['mailBcc']);
    //Is there an attachment
    if(!empty($res['mailFile'])){
    foreach($res['mailFile'] as $f){
        $email->attachFromPath($f['sFiles'],$f['sFilesName']);
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to urlencode the data before putting it into a URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly URL encode a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744888/how-to-properly-url-encode-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's resolved